# Exception при strncpy_s

Tags: c, строки

Есть вот такая вот функция (недоделанная):

```
void fixNumber(char *number)
{
    char const* internatFormat = "+380";
    char tempNumber[NUMBERLEN];
    unsigned int index = strlen(number) - 10;
    if (strncmp(number, internatFormat, 4) != 0) {
        strncpy_s(tempNumber, 10, number + index, NUMBERLEN);
    }

}
```

Вылетает exception при использовании функции strncpy_s, причём я проверял: все аргументы расположены правильно, буфер не переполнен. в *number находится "0675895614"

Спасибо за помощь заранее.

Comment: Что такое `NUMBERLEN`? Почему в вопросе отсутствует эта критическая информация?

Comment: Извините, NUMBEREN = 16

Comment: Какой компилятор вы используете? Это стандартный  `strncpy_s` или `strncpy_s` из Visual Studio?

Comment: из Visual Studio. Даже не знал, что есть разница.

Comment: Нет, похоже, что существенной разницы нет.

Answer (score 1):

Функция `strncpy_s` вторым параметром принимает размер буфера, а четвертым - количество копируемых символов. У вас же как будто все наоборот.

В ситуации, когда указанный вами размер принимающего буфера недостаточен для того, чтобы принять копируемые данные (включая замыкающий `\0`), то вызывается "обработчик неправильного параметра".

В вашем примере копируемые данные требуют буфера размера 11, а вы вторым параметром передали 10. Вызывается вышеупомянутый обработчик, который вы по-видимому и назвали "exception".

Comment: Ох, как же оказалось всё просто. Спасибо большое!